# Cross class calling through 'sibling' inheritance?

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I'm wondering if what I have created is valid and 'nice' - or actually a mess

I have a class that has a method which calls a function in another class. However, it is only 'visible' by the fact these two classes are brought together in another child class. If somebody is just looking at this method they may wonder where this is actually located - it is not clear.

Am I doing something wrong here, or something common in Python?

```
class A():
      def __init__(self):
            pass

      def register_urc(self, text):
            print(text)

class B(A):
      def __init__(self):
            A.__init__(self)

class C():
      def __init__(self):
            self.register_urc("Hello World")

class Z(B, C):
      def __init__(self):
            B.__init__(self)
            C.__init__(self)

      def test(self):
            print("finished")

z = Z()
z.test()
```

What I get is:

```
Hello World
finished.
```

I assume this is working because I'm referencing Z's 'self' and passing that down to all other classes.

Comment: What is your expected case here ? Are you concerned about chaining or concerned about readability.

Comment: Readability. In class C there is no such method called register_urc() and class C does not inherit from anything. Only if you look where C is inherited and then look down into Class B do you then see register_urc() is actually found in class A

Comment: Here python is is doing what you asked. If C has no role over the Z then don't inherit it. Remember YAGNI (You aren't gonna need it)  and remember being pythonic 'Explicit is better than implicit.' In concise, re-work your design and try to be explicit as you can.